# Rails 6 Bcrypt vs Passenger error on Production

Tags: passenger, ruby-on-rails-6, bcrypt-ruby

After changing my ssl settings and restarting my Nginx, I started to receive the following error in the Passenger startup:

```
Before process_action callback :ensure_user_signed_in has not been defined (ArgumentError)
```

I am running Rails 6, Nginx/Passenger. The protected area is a single namespace only.

sessions_controller

```
class SessionsController < NamespaceController
    skip_before_action :ensure_user_signed_in, only: [:new, :create]

    # Present login form
    def new
    end

    # Create Session
    def create
        user = User.where(email: params[:email]).first

        if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
            session[:user_id] = user.id
            redirect_to '/namespace/adminhub'
        else
            redirect_to new_sessions_path, alert: 'Unable to authenticate'
        end
    end

    # Logout
    def destroy
        reset_session
        redirect_to root_path
    end

end
```

Namespace_controller

```
class NamespaceController < ApplicationController
    before_action :ensure_user_signed_in

    private
        def ensure_user_signed_in
            unless current_user.present?
            redirect_to new_sessions_path, alert: 'Must be signed in.'
        end
    end

    def current_user
        if session.has_key? :user_id
            @current_user ||=User.find(session[:user_id])
        end
    end
    helper_method :current_user
  end
```

EDIT: I have attempted to undo my ssl changes in nginx and also to restart passenger, neither seem to be the cause of this issue. Interestingly, when I first pushed out the changes with the Bcrpyt, the page loaded without issue and ran properly, as it does in my development area. It was not until I had to restart the nginx process that this error has come to light.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot more digging and trials, I found [this article](https://github.com/nsarno/knock/issues/138). In my controller, I added `raise: false` to the end of my line.

`skip_before_action :ensure_user_signed_in, only: [:new, :create], raise: false`

And I was working after that. Although, I am not positive why this worked, it did. I will be continuing my research into this.